# 'freestyle' SQL Execution

Tags: amazon-redshift

So in MSSQL I can execute ad-hoc SQL statements e.g.

```
if exists (select 1 from sys.databases where [name] = 'Admin')
begin
    print('do something ');
    create schema lala;
    create table #temp(dummy nvarchar(128));
    insert into #temp(dummy) values('lala');
end
```

In Redshift I've been unable to do anything similar outside of a formal function or procedure.

Am I missing something, or is this just something that Redshift simply does not do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you look at Lambda functions and Step Functions in AWS.  Redshift is part of the larger ecosystem that is AWS and which Redshift supports some basic "operating" level coding, more advanced functionality is done at the ecosystem level.  This means that not everything that can be done inside of other database is done inside of Redshift.

While this can be a bit of a learning curve the flexibility and power that can be enabled is quite large with this approach.  For example a Lambda can perform the operations you mention in your example AND also add this schema and table to the Glue catalog, organize objects on S3 and enable Athena querying of these objects all in the same function.  You can do what you describe in a stored procedure and the scope is just Redshift Or you perform this at the AWS level and update your data system across the entire data solution.  A different way to view the division of work across systems.

Comment: I get where you are coming from if I consider a full scale final deployment scenario.
However if you are just developing early stages;  coding lambdas, going through source control and all that overhead - is a bit overkill for what should be 60 seconds worth of code to try something out that may never go into production at all.

Comment: In that case may I suggest a shell script.  I use 'psql' (the postgres CLI) to launch commands to Redshift and parse the results in bash for such one-off experiments.  If scripting isn't your jam then python and java have the libraries to do this.  UDFs are an option but I find these to end up being a long-term support problem and creating DB lock-in.

Comment: Sorry - stored procedure, not UDF